# defaultState of Redux store from API

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I make the default state of my Redux store be data that comes in from an API request?

I want to make a request like this, then pass that returned data as the `defaultState` when creating the store:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/api', true);
request.onload = function load() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    const data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
  }
};


const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, enhancers);
```

Comment: If it comes from the an ajax request is it really default? Why not have default be empty object / array / undefined then run your ajax request and populate the next state?

Comment: @azium how can I do that? I tried `store.replaceState(data)` which didn't work.

Comment: Dispatch an action in your root component's `componentDidMount`. nothing fancy

Comment: @azium I put:

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(store);
}

to which I get store is undefined

Comment: You don't access the store like that.. you connect your component with `connect` and then `this.props.dispatch(yourAction())` which your redux store knows how to handle just like every other dispatch / action in your app. Are you reading the docs? http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: @azium I am using connect, but I have a component that is routed to BEFORE the connected component view, so I'm confused on the setup.

Comment: you must have a root component somewhere.. (typically called `<App />`) dispatch the action there

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to set an asynchronously loaded state as a default, you should try loading it before starting the application in `index.js`:

```
import reducer from './reducer';

function asyncStateLoadingFunction(callback) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/api', true);
  request.onload = function load() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      callback(JSON.parse(this.response));
    } else {
      callback(null, 'Error occured');
    }
  };
};

Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  asyncStateLoadingFunction((result) => {
    resolve(result);
  }, (error) => {
    throw new Error(error);
  });
})
.then((initialState) => {
  // NOTE Create the Redux store, routers etc now
  const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#app')
  );
});
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I'm after; where should I be defining `asyncStateLoadingFunction`?

Comment: I updated the answer and put the `asyncStateLoadingFunction` in the code there.

Comment: Oh man, this is so close.  I'm getting a parsing error here: `(callback = () => {}) => {` which is stopping my whole app from compiling; any thoughts?
The error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token (`

Comment: Well, I'd say just remove the default parameter: `let asyncStateLoadingFunction(callback) => { ...` and it should work just fine.

Comment: Still the same error. I'm sorry, I'm not really familiar with using functions in promises so maybe I'm missing something obvious

Comment: There was a problem with the `asyncStateLoadingFunction`, fixed it in the answer code.

Comment: Now I'm getting `undefined is not a promise`. A quick Google tells me that the `resolve` might be in the wrong place, but I'm not sure what the right place is.

Comment: I definitely see where to get the data going, but I'm not understanding where exactly to put the callback (outside of the `if`?)

Comment: It is already in my code snippet, see the `onload` part - use the callback to finish the function, therefore I put it in the place where I already fetched the data from the API and I can pass it forward.